# Border-top conflict with left and right border?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML like this :

```
<style>
#footer{
width: 777px;
padding: 20px 24px;
background: white;
margin: 0px auto 25px;
border-right: 1px solid #eee;
border-left: 1px solid #eee;
border-top: 12px solid #bbb;
background: #fbfbfb;
}
</style>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

You can see : A haft of top border is not displayed normally ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf7sa/)). 
So, solution for this? (Do not create any `div` more.)

Comment: That's normal behavior. How do you expect it to display?

Comment: i think you might need a comprehensive understanding of [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)

Comment: This is not possible because every part(i.e border) of div taking there space, this is region your design not look good, the solution of that is you will try to make different div for ever portion like border right for one div, border left for other div, and for content other.

Comment: BoltClock is alluding to the correct statement.  Borders meet at a diagonal. They do not overlap or give precedence to one side over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on your requirement of not adding elements, I came up with this hack of a solution just for kicks.

```
#footer:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:349px;
  height:20px;
  background:#BBB;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/xf7sa/2/